# How to extract email address

Tags: excel, vba, web, screen-scraping

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim ie, items, elem As Object
    Dim i, j, k, l As Integer

    i = 2
    k = 2
    l = 2

    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.application")

    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate "https://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/A3NEAETOSXDBOM/"

    Do While ie.busy Or ie.readystate <> 4

    Loop

    For i = 0 To 500
        On Error Resume Next

        Range("A" & i).Value = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a").Item(i).innertext

    Next i

End Sub
```

I am looking to retrieve email address which appears in the left of the page as "send email" & email address appears after clicking on it.

Note: You must be logged in to view Send email option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code before your End Sub:

```
Set sendAnEmail = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("a-link-normal pr-email").Item(0)

sendAnEmail.Click  

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

retrievedEmail = sendAnEmail.innerText

MsgBox retrievedEmail
```

However, you should take a look at Amazon's Politics about Web-Scraping as this could not be 100% legal

Comment: I have tried this. but it's not working. :( please suggest or provide full code on command button

Comment: it worked somehow. but outlook email editor is popping up. any solution to close it or kill outlook everytime i run the code?